# TwinCAT PLC HMI Web SPA

Tags: single-page-application, plc, twincat, twincat-hmi

I've got a question regarding HMI development. I already have an overview how to develop the HMI UI app, but Im wondering is there a possibility to a bit decouple view layer from the HMI SDK.

Would it be possible to develop a HMI frontend app as a single HTML app with javascript as SPA (single page app) and only write and read values from the HMI app? The front end app would know the keys for mapped variables to read and write. HMI server would point to a plain html file and instead to a view.

The advantage would be that frontend developer would not have to use this complicated PLC stack - he would develop standalone app, he would know the variable keys and he could develop it separately and then just deploy in into TwinCAT project for veriifaction.

Would that make sense? Or is it much better to develop the HMI in the GUI editor provided by Beckhoff, because all is much more optimised?

Answer (score 2):

What you would like to do is offered by the [TwinCat HMI](https://www.beckhoff.com/de-de/produkte/automation/twincat-hmi/) which displays HMI as HMTL with CSS enriched with Java Script. You can use predifined controls, configure them, create new one based on existing or even write new one as text code. It is very powerful tool, that handles a lot under the hood and it's adressed to more complex application.

However what you ask for you could do using [TC1000 | TwinCAT ADS.NET V6](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/index.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_ads.net/index.html&id=207622008965200265) , C# and Windows Forms. This solution would use Beckhoff's ADS and it is free of charge. It should be also secured since the ADS commication is so, but it requires Windows on the HMI-device.
Beckhoff provides even some [examples](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_c/112599819.html&id=) of using their ADS C# libraries and I know from their support/application engineers that it is a working option for a simpler application.